# Messagebox in CMainFrame OnCreate

Tags: mfc, modal-dialog, oncreate

I have an old MFC application with an OnCreate function that spans upwards of 200 lines.

```
CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
...
PostMessage(LOAD_IMAGES,0,0);
...
ValidatePermissions();
...
}
```

The `LOAD_IMAGES` is a user message whose handler tries to Load images which had been unsaved from the last session.. basically it tries to create a new CDocument...

The `ValidatePermissions` function pops up a modal messagebox if it finds any permissions missing..

I notice that if I have the modal message box pop up, then I get a crash when LOAD_IMAGES handler fires (since it cannot create a CDocument, I think it is because the CMainFrame has not yet created).

How should I be handling such a case. Is there any documentation that suggests not to have modal messageboxes in the OnCreate?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the call to ValidatePermissions to the message handler for LOAD_IMAGES. That should let the window creating complete before you let the message box pump messages.

Comment: So basically I should move anything that may cause a modal messagebox to run from a PostMessage call?

Comment: A message box pumps messages, which introduces the possibility of something reentering your wndproc (i.e. calling an MFC message handler while you are still in another message handler.) PostMessage is not the cause of the problem: Many messages can cause reentry during a message box.

Comment: OK, so basically if there is message pumping going on, there is a risk.

Calling the messagebox from the postmessage call would allow for the OnCreate message handler to complete before the messagebox pump starts.